# How to fix a broken End Gateway in Minecraft Survival?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently came across a problem where, in fixing something else by copying region files, a couple of the End Gateways in my Survival game stopped working as designed; instead they dumped me in the void to eat vacuum.

Is there a way to fix the End Gateway portals that are misbehaving, or do I just have to live with taking another portal that still works?

Information: this was in Minecraft 1.12.2 Java Edition, in a single user world. I should also add the OS on all my computers is Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but I worked out the following by looking at Youtube videos about custom portals. It involves using commands, so in survival you have to temporarily enable cheats to do it.

First, make a backup of your entire world directory, in case something goes wrong!

Make a note of the coordinates of the portal(s) that are not working correctly. You can do this very easily using `f3` and pointing at the portal. Possibly not quite so easy is to find the coordinates of the return portal. If you can use another portal to travel there you can use `f3` in the same way to find its coordinates. Alternatively if you have a backup of your world you may be able to use that to find the right coordinates, or you can find an alternative 'safe' place to point the portal to. You may find @Fabian's tips in the comments below this answer useful to get the coordinates.

Turn on cheats by opening your world to LAN (`ESC`, then `Open to LAN`, toggle `Allow Cheats: ON` and then `Start LAN World`).

Use the following sequence of commands (coordinates for the portal are `x`, `y`, `z`; coordinates for the destination are `m`, `n`, `o`):

```
/setblock x y z air 0 replace
/setblock x y z end_gateway 0 replace {ExitPortal:{X:m,Y:n,Z:o},ExactTeleport:0}
```

The first line deletes the malfunctioning gateway block at `x`, `y`, `z` and replaces it with air. I found this was necessary because I could not directly replace the gateway block with another one. Without this you just get a message to say the block was not placed.

The second line places a new gateway block in the same location, and points it to teleport to coordinates `m`, `n`, `o`, with the 'normal' end gateway behaviour.

Save your game and restart it to close the LAN, and the portal should now work.

If you are unable to find the correct coordinates for the destination, it may be safer to find another place to use as the teleport target, and use `ExactTeleport:1`.

Comment: "not quite so easy is to find the coordinates of the return portal"? Why? It's always at x=0 and z=0 on the ground and you can find out the same way as for the overworld portal.

Comment: Wait, are you talking about end gateways or the end portal? I kept wondering how in the world an end portal can break and how replacing it with air and back with a portal would help anything, because it's not even a tile entity. If you mean "end gateway", please use that term consistently.

Comment: Just the third command should be enough, you don't need #1, #2 and #4. Did you test going through without using command #2?

Comment: @Fabian you got it, this is about the gateways to the islands.

Comment: Then please change the question and answer accordingly. While you're at it, you can also add the "faq" tag to indicate that this a post to share your knowledge. And you can mark your own answer as accepted, except if you want to wait for other answers first. But I think you already found the right principle, just a few steps aren't necessary.

Comment: Restarting the game also isn't necessary and it's automatically saved every few seconds anyway.

Comment: @Fabian this was a problem in a survival world, so I think it was necessary to have lines 1 and 4. The first time I tried placing the new portal it did not let me, but the game allowed me to remove it and replace it with air, hence line 2. And saving and restarting closes the LAN.

Comment: Tip: You can find the intended way out by using "recreate world" and then going through the gateway. To get the gateway, you just have to enter `/setblock ~ ~ ~ end_portal` to go to the end and then `/kill @e[type=ender_dragon]` to kill the dragon and generate the gateway.

Comment: When you set the gamemode to Creative before generating a world, cheats are automatically enabled, but it's a separate property. `/gamemode` is already a cheat, so the fact that you can use it proves that you can already use them. | If you replace a gateway with a gateway, nothing looks different. Did you get an error message? What version are you in? There were a few issues with tile entities, `/fill` and `/setblock` and error messages before, but I think they are fixed now. | You should say in the answer that closing and reopening the world is to disable cheats/LAN.

Comment: @Fabian thanks for those tips, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I would save a copy of the map, then use an external editor (MCEdit, for example) to delete the chunks for the end in the copy. That would force the chunks to repopulate on entering the portal. If that doesn't work, maybe replace the active portal by pasting over it with one that has not yet been activated, then in game reactivate the portal. if neither method works, try both? if you've already defeated the dragon and/or have things built in the end, this method wouldn't be advisable.

Comment: This is a good idea, but it was not an option for me because my OS is Linux and MCEdit does not work there AFAIK. NBTExplorer sort-of enables you to look at things, but I found previously all sorts of issues actually editing things with it running under Mono. Also, the reason I was messing around copying region files in the first place was because deleting them did not resolve the original problem, which was to do with failed/damaged creation of end cities.

Comment: @Bobble well, there *is* MCEdit for Linux, and there *is* Wine, soo...

Comment: @alex2003super I'm always using the windows version, and it's been a while. I had completely forgotten about there being a Linux version of MCEdit.