# Fixing Remote End Gateway Portals in Minecraft Survival 1.13+

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was cleaning up an older world that I play on with my kids, and removed all of the End Island chunks via MCEdit. After going back through our End gateway, we still teleport to the same remote Island, but the two End gateway portals to bring us back to the main island are gone.

Using the https://mcstacker.net/ `/setblock` feature, I was able to get an updated version of the fix mentioned in https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/324643/220481 for 1.13+

```
/setblock -77 75 -56 minecraft:air replace
/setblock -77 75 -56 minecraft:end_gateway{Age:0,ExactTeleport:0b,ExitPortal:{X:-982,Y:58,Z:-694}} replace
```

However, after going through it, there are still no portals on the end island to return. Do I need to run a similar command on the end islands to regenerate those portals taking us back to the main island? Is there any way to have them generated again by the game?

Comment: Did you run them while you were in the area you wanted to place them? I've never seen `/setblock` fail without an error message.

Comment: Setblock did work for the gateway on the main island, but after going through, the "remote" end gateway on the outer islands did not respawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End gateways are generated with the terrain. And generated structures only appear once (would be pretty bad otherwise if you removed a tree, built your base there and when you came back, the tree overwrote it).
So you'll have to create the gateways back yourself:

```
/setblock -982 58 -694 end_gateway{ExactTeleport:0,ExitPortal:{X:-77,Y:75,Z:-56}}
```

Comment: Thanks. That did work!

I had initially assumed that going through the gateway would recreate it on the other side, similar to how nether portals work. After seeing the commands used to create new end gateways though, I suppose it makes sense that would be handled differently.